# Using webpack to create angular1 and angular2 hybrid app throw upgrade static error

Tags: angularjs, webpack, angular2-routing

I am trying to use angular upgrade path to use angular1 and angular2 using webpack loader. When I take angular1 and just load angular2 it all works fine and the reason is upgrade static file error which is mentioned below

my angular bootstrap file is as following:

```
import 'angular2-universal-polyfills/browser';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformUniversalDynamic } from 'angular2-universal';
import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import 'bootstrap';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { UpgradeModule } from '@angular/upgrade/static';


// Enable either Hot Module Reloading or production mode
if (module['hot']) {
    module['hot'].accept();
    module['hot'].dispose(() => { platform.destroy(); });
} else {
    enableProdMode();
}

// Boot the application, either now or when the DOM content is loaded
const platform = platformUniversalDynamic();
const bootApplication = () => {
    //platform.bootstrapModule(AppModule);
    platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule).then(platformRef => {
        console.info("Angular 2 bootstrapping");
        const upgrade = platformRef.injector.get(UpgradeModule) as UpgradeModule;
        upgrade.bootstrap(document.documentElement, ["app"], { strictDi: true });
    });
};
if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
    bootApplication();
} else {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', bootApplication);
}
```

And the error I am getting is below

Error  in ./~/@angular/upgrade/static.js
Module parse failed: C:\TFS\PostAnything\Postanything.Web.Client\node_modules\@angular\upgrade\static.js Line 8: Unexpected token
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|  * found in the LICENSE file at https://angular.io/license
|  */
| export { downgradeComponent } from './src/aot/downgrade_component';
| export { downgradeInjectable } from './src/aot/downgrade_injectable';
| export { UpgradeComponent } from './src/aot/upgrade_component';
 @ ./ClientApp/boot-client.ts 9:15-49

Comment: I have the exact same issue. Still looking for a solution.

Comment: I got it working and have created very basic github repo with no extra baggage. Just be aware that payload will be very huge coz of Hybrid app. Will post my answer soon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved this issue finally by taking guidance from other GitHub repo and created my own to have Angular1 and Angular hybrid app with Webpack.

[Click here for Github repo link](https://github.com/atul221282/webpack_angular_hybrid/tree/master/src/WebpackDemo)